# I cannot access files in protected directory flutter even after permission

Tags: android, flutter, storage, native

I have used **ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE** to let the user choose a folder **[So to avoid using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]** but couldn't view i.e. Read the files inside the hidden

Already tried all the file piker libraries

I cannot access files in this directory even after giving permission from Document Tree to a produced directory in android studio which is below:

```
'/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses'
```

below is the result I get when I list the files in the above directory but am unable to read the files using **Image.file()** in flutter URI permission also granted which are as follows

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
```

below is one of the results I get when I list the files, its accessible in native android code but not in flutter

```
'content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses%2Fa9e8797092cd4bfeb6e426dfa1be7a84.jpg'
```

following code is used to get permission from files using native android code in mainactivity file

```
private fun grantAndroid11StorageAccessPermission() {
println("mydhfhsdkfsd 00")
if (isMyPackedgeInstalled("com.whatsapp")) {
    val intent: Intent
    val storageManager: StorageManager =
        getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
    val whatsappfolderdir: String = if (File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString() + "/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses"
        ).isDirectory()
    ) {
        "Android%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses"
    } else {
        "WhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses"
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        intent = storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()

        val scheme: String =
            (intent.getParcelableExtra<android.os.Parcelable>("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI") as Uri)
                .toString()
                .replace("/root/", "/document/")


        val stringBuilder = "$scheme%3A$whatsappfolderdir"
        intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", Uri.parse(stringBuilder))
        println("mydhfhsdkfsd $stringBuilder")
    } else {
        intent = Intent("android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE")
        intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", Uri.parse(whatsappfolderdir))
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivityForResult(
        intent,
        OPEN_DOCOMENT_TREE_REQUEST_CODE
    )
    return
} else {
    Toast.makeText(
        this@MainActivity,
        "Error getting ",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show()

}
}
```

following function is used to retrieve the files list

```
    private fun getDataFromWhatsAppFolder(): Array<DocumentFile>? {
    try {
        val fromTreeUri: DocumentFile? = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(
            applicationContext,
            Uri.parse(namedataprefs)
        )
        if (fromTreeUri!!.exists() && fromTreeUri.isDirectory() && fromTreeUri.canRead() && fromTreeUri.canWrite()) {
            return fromTreeUri.listFiles()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
    return null
}
```

if complete Mainactivity file is required I will add it below also

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.flutterapp


import android.R.attr.path
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.os.storage.StorageManager
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.Nullable
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import java.io.File


class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
private val CHANNEL = "apilevel"


private val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 1235
private val OPEN_DOCOMENT_TREE_REQUEST_CODE = 1014


var filesList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()
private var namedataprefs: String? = null


private var callResult: MethodChannel.Result? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine!!)


    val prefs: SharedPreferences =
        getSharedPreferences("whatsapp_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    namedataprefs = prefs.getString("whatsapp", "")


    MethodChannel(
        flutterEngine!!.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
        CHANNEL
    ).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->

        callResult = result
        if (call.method == "getapilevel") {

            Log.d("fffffffffff", (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT).toString())
            result.success((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT).toString())
        } else if (call.method == "whatsapplist") {
            var mylis: List<String> = ArrayList<String>()
            if (getDataFromWhatsAppFolder() != null) {
                Log.d("fffffffffff", "folder done")
                mylis = getData()




                Log.d("fffffffffff", "folder datalengthc " + File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses").canRead())
                val directory: File = File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses")
                val files = directory.listFiles()
                Log.d("Files", "Size: " + files.size)
                for (i in files.indices) {
                    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].name)
                }

            }

            result.success(mylis)

        } else if (call.method == "whatsapp") {

            Log.d("fffffffffff", "grantwhatsapp")


            if (getDataFromWhatsAppFolder() == null) {

                grantAndroid11StorageAccessPermission()

            }

        } else {
            result.notImplemented()
        }
    }
}


private fun isMyPackedgeInstalled(packageName: String?): Boolean {
    return try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName!!, 0)
        true
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        false
    }
}


private fun grantAndroid11StorageAccessPermission() {
    println("mydhfhsdkfsd 00")
    if (isMyPackedgeInstalled("com.whatsapp")) {
        val intent: Intent
        val storageManager: StorageManager =
            getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
        val whatsappfolderdir: String = if (File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString() + "/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses"
            ).isDirectory()
        ) {
            "Android%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses"
        } else {
            "WhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses"
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            intent = storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()

            val scheme: String =
                (intent.getParcelableExtra<android.os.Parcelable>("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI") as Uri)
                    .toString()
                    .replace("/root/", "/document/")


            val stringBuilder = "$scheme%3A$whatsappfolderdir"
            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", Uri.parse(stringBuilder))
            println("mydhfhsdkfsd $stringBuilder")
        } else {
            intent = Intent("android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE")
            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", Uri.parse(whatsappfolderdir))
        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
        startActivityForResult(
            intent,
            OPEN_DOCOMENT_TREE_REQUEST_CODE
        )
        return
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
            this@MainActivity,
            "Error getting ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()

    }
}


private fun getDataFromWhatsAppFolder(): Array<DocumentFile>? {
    try {
        val fromTreeUri: DocumentFile? = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(
            applicationContext,
            Uri.parse(namedataprefs)
        )
        if (fromTreeUri!!.exists() && fromTreeUri.isDirectory() && fromTreeUri.canRead() && fromTreeUri.canWrite()) {
            return fromTreeUri.listFiles()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
    return null
}


private fun getData(): List<String> {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
        if (filesList != null) {
            filesList = ArrayList<String>()
        }

        try {
            val allFileswhatsapp: Array<DocumentFile>? = getDataFromWhatsAppFolder()
            ///val allFileswhat: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf(Array<DocumentFile>)

            val allFileswhat: Array<DocumentFile> = allFileswhatsapp!!
            //  allFileswhat.toMutableList().addAll(allFileswhatsapp)
            // allFileswhat.addAll(allFileswhatsapp)


            for (allFile in allFileswhat) {
                // val file: Uri = allFile.getUri()
                val file: Uri = allFile.getUri()

                if (!allFile.getUri().toString().contains(".nomedia") && !allFile.getUri()
                        .toString().equals("")
                ) {
                    val fromTreeUri1 = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        Uri.parse(allFile.getUri().toString())
                    )

                    if (fromTreeUri1 != null) {
                      //  moveFile(fromTreeUri1.uri.toString());
                        filesList.add(fromTreeUri1.uri.toString())
                        Log.d("fffffffffff added list ", fromTreeUri1.uri.toString())
                        Log.d("fffffffffff added segm ", fromTreeUri1.uri.lastPathSegment.toString())
                    }

                }
            }

            filesList.add("/storage/emulated/0/Download/wester.jpg")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    return filesList
}


@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, @Nullable data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == OPEN_DOCOMENT_TREE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == -1) {
        val uri: Uri? = data!!.data
        try {


            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                uri!!,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            )
            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                uri!!,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
            )

            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                uri,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
            )


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        namedataprefs = uri!!.toString()
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor =
            getSharedPreferences("whatsapp_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
        editor.putString("whatsapp", uri.toString())
        editor.apply()

        Log.d("fffffffffff", "my string location is " + uri.toString())


        var mylis: List<String> = ArrayList<String>()
        if (getDataFromWhatsAppFolder() != null) {
            Log.d("fffffffffff", "folder done")
            mylis = getData()
            Log.d("fffffffffff", "folder datalength " + mylis.size)


        }

        callResult!!.success(mylis)

    }





}




fun moveFile(sourceFile: String?): Boolean {
    val despath =
        "/storage/emulated/0/Download/tempwhatsapp/" + File(
            sourceFile
        ).name
    val destUri = Uri.fromFile(File(despath))
    try {
        val `is` = contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse(sourceFile))
        val os = contentResolver.openOutputStream(destUri, "w")
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        while (true) {
            val read = `is`!!.read(buffer)
            if (read > 0) {
                os!!.write(buffer, 0, read)
            } else {
                `is`.close()
                os!!.flush()
                os.close()
                val intent = Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE")
                intent.data = destUri
                sendBroadcast(intent)
                return true
            }
        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return false
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: `grantAndroid11StorageAccessPermission()` That is nonsense. You cannot grant access permission. You can get access permission in inActivityResult. Check if you get it. And be glad if you got.

Comment: sir i get permission successfully and get the files list successfully but flutter is not loading it